# What are "instances" and what are "attributes" in time-series dataset?

Tags: time-series, dataset

I have a table with 370 entitled columns and 140256 time-titled rows in [`ElectricityLoadDiagrams20112014 Data Set`](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/ElectricityLoadDiagrams20112014#). Nevertheless, home page says

```
Number of Instances: 370
Number of Attributes: 140256
```

Is this just a reverse mistake, or it is some sense here?

Comment: In what sense is this a mistake?  And does the terminology used by "home page" (whatever that might refer to) even matter?

Comment: I would say a raw is an "instance", and a column is an "attribute".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a mistake on the home page where it states the number of instances and attributes for the ElectricityLoadDiagrams20112014 Data Set.  there are 140256 instances (rows) and 370 attributes (columns) in the dataset, which is the reverse of what is stated on the home page.

It's possible that the mistake was made inadvertently, as the numbers could be confused if the dataset is represented as a matrix or table with instances as rows and attributes as columns.